# A problem using ListView

Tags: android, listview

Hi geeks！
Here is a problem using ListView.

When generating a single list item view, in the method of BaseAdapter.getView, some continuous async remote data request may be issued, like getting the photo of a person.

But when the response is back, the list item view might be reused, as the mechanism of ListView works. I cannot find the right view to put the response to.

How did you guys fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

As you say, there is a good chance that by the time you've loaded the image that the list item is no longer visible or even existing. So you can check what is on screen using [ListView.getFirstVisiblePosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getFirstVisiblePosition%28%29) and ListView.getLastVisiblePosition(), if it is onScreen get the item and set the image. Otherwise you have to cache the image (either memory or sd-card depending on how many images and the size of them) and next time getView() is called for that item just use the cached image.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what your after is "lazy image loading" + caching. I got my implementation going via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012). The package is called LazyList.

I hope this helps

[image]